# two Submit buttons, using One form, in different table cells? is it possible?

Tags: html, css, forms, submit

I have this code:

```
      <tr>
        <td><form action="1.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
          <input name="a" type="hidden" value="a"/>
          <input type="submit" class="class one" value="submit-1"></form></td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td><form action="1.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
          <input name="a" type="hidden" value="a"/>
          <input type="submit" class="class two" value="submit-2"></form></td>
      </tr>
```

Both forms are exactly the same (Action,input values), only difference is that I want a different submit button in these two tables cells.

Therefore, is there a way to use the `<form>` tag only once, yet have such two submit buttons?
(both less code, and also that way, in the future I can modify the form only at one place, rather go through each cell)

I've tried ending the first form in the last cell, and keep only a the submit part in that cell, but it didn't work since the first cell's `</td>` is at the way. putting the form right after `<tr>` didn't work neither.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why do you need 2 different submit buttons, but if it is going about using one form... you can just put all table in form tag:

```
<form action="">
    <table>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" class="class one" value="submit-1"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" class="class two" value="submit-2"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks but I'm afraid I can't use this, as I want to have different forms in each table row, though in each row, I want to have the same form, with two submit buttons in 2 cells from that row.